# Flutter image_picker crash only in the Play Store Live version

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, imagepicker

UPDATE: We discovered that the problem might be caused by the flutter version 2.10 on the computer that was uploaded to the store. We will remove We_chat and downgrade the version to 2.8.1 and then upload new bundle version again.

There is an app where we use image_picker(0.8.3) and wechat_assets_picker(^6.3.1) together. It works fine on emulator and normal device. When we get the release apk, it works smoothly on the devices we installed it on. However, in the same version that we bought bundle and uploaded to the store, when the image_picker structure works in live (camera or gallery), the app crashes in the background.
We are using the new versions of both packages.

There is no error on the iOS side.

We don't know if it's causing a problem when generating google bundle as both packages access the gallery.
We don't know if it will continue without any problems if we put it on google play as an apk. (we will try this)
we only have logs where we get the Abort error ( sentry and crashlytic ) without details ...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the error still exist try this plugin

```
  file_picker: ^4.1.6
```

This works for me